# How do I convert object into Map style JSON to send it through Get request in Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, get

Object Model:

```
public class NotificationSettingsDto {

private Boolean campaignEvents;
private Boolean drawResultEvents;
private Boolean transactionEvents;
private Boolean userWonEvents;
}
```

Say I'm getting this object

```
new NotificationSettingsDto(true,true,true,true);
```

through spring get request.

And this is the JSON value I want to get from this object.

```
[{"name" : "campaignEvents" ,  "value" : true},
 {"name" : "drawResultEvents" ,  "value" : true},
 {"name" : "transactionEvents" , "value" : true},
 {"name" : "userWonEvents",    "value" : true}]
```

Comment: can't you just manually create it? say a class that takes another class and create the json format you want.

Comment: The JSON you put in your post is not valid. Please clarify if it is just typo or you mean it so.

Comment: @nafas Thanks! Others gave me same clue. Check my answer.

Comment: @MarioSantini yes sorry about that. Fixed the typo. I already found a solution. Check it out if you are interested.

Comment: @Amiko excellent mate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved it :

```
Arrays.asList(  new CustomPair<>("campaignEvents", nsDto.getCampaignEvents()),
                new CustomPair<>("drawResults", nsDto.getDrawResultEvents()),
                new CustomPair<>("transactionEvents", nsDto.getTransactionEvents()),
                new CustomPair<>("userWonEvents", nsDto.getUserWonEvents())
```

`nsDto` stands for `NotificationSettingsDto`. Whereas `CustomPair` is:

```
public class CustomPair<K, V> {
private K key;
private V value; 
}
```

@nafas was right in the comment section. Thanks. It's not the cleanest Solution but it does it

Resulted JSON :

```
[{"key":"campaignEvents","value":true},
 {"key":"drawResults","value":true},
 {"key":"transactionEvents","value":true},
 {"key":"userWonEvents","value":true}]
```

Comment: You gotta love requirements!

Comment: @Steve11235, Yeah, sometimes it drives us to dirty solutions. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use  Jackson 2.x ObjectMapper class.

```
NotificationSettingsDto obj = new NotificationSettingsDto(true,true,true,true);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
```

But your json string is not valid. This is how your json would look like:

```
{
    "campaignEvents": true,
    "drawResultEvents": true,
    "transactionEvents": true,
    "userWonEvents": true
}
```

EDIT: You can also do it using Gson as mentioned in the comment.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
NotificationSettingsDto obj = new NotificationSettingsDto(true,true,true,true);
String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Comment: @Steve11235 Yes, it's correct format. I agree. Thanks for the answer. I was doing that way but I was specifically asked to do the way I posted in my question. I fixed the type in my question and posted my answer. Check it out.